# How to use unassigned input from while loop to add to a value

Tags: python, while-loop

```
total = 0
while int(input()) != 0:
  total += ??input??
print(total)
```

How do I pull the while input into the sum variable?

I can't find anything like this existing but don't know if that is because it is an unasked question or if it just incredibly foolish.

I am trying to add an unknown number of inputs ending when the input is 0.
Any help or pointing in the right direction would be helpful.

Comment: You can't. You have to store the user input in a variable. That's what variables are for.

Comment: @Dave Can you please be more clear what exactly you want to ask. It will be more helpful for others who are willing to answer.

Comment: Can you pls give an example of what u need..as it is not clear from your post

Comment: I need to sum an unknown number of inputs ending when the input value is 0.  Using a while loop to process the inputs as long as they are not 0 is the best way I can think of to accomplish that.  The problem is that I now have to sum those inputs.  Example: input 5 7 6 0 output 18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
total = 0
while True:
    x = int(input())
    if x == 0:
        break
    total += x
print(total)
```

I prefer the above because it has no repetition, but sometimes people do something like this instead:

```
total = 0
x = int(input())
while x != 0:
    total += x
    x = int(input())
print(total)
```

Comment: Thank you!  That is exactly what I was looking for.  I am new at this and didn't realize I could set the variable before the loop and have it still process.